# Question about .NET dependency resolution of System dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-management, csproj

I need help understanding how the `dotnet` SDK resolves dependencies, as there is something missing in my understanding that confuses me.

My question in a nutshell: **When given a target framework of `net7.0`, why is system dependencies like `System.Net.Http` still showing an earlier version (`4.3.0`)?**

Best to give an example from the code.

This is my `.csproj` file:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Doing a `dotnet restore` on this renders (among other things) the following dependency graph for `project.assets.json`:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "targets": {
    "net7.0": {
      "Castle.Core/4.4.1": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
(...)
        },
```

And a bit further down:

```
"NETStandard.Library/1.6.1": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
       (...)
          "System.Net.Http": "4.3.0",
```

This does not make sense to me. As I understand, Nuget aims for [lowest applicable version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#lowest-applicable-version) which therefore should be locked to `7.0.0` given the target framework, right?

If I try to do a `dotnet publish` as a self-contained deployment, it the `deps.json` generated **still** shows `System.Net.Http` version `4.3.0` **despite** the assembly versions showing `7.0.0`:

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0/osx-x64",
    "signature": ""
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0": {},
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0/osx-x64": {
      "IfDotNoIssue/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "NSubstitute": "4.3.0",
          "runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.osx-x64": "7.0.5"
        },
(...)
"runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.osx-x64/7.0.5": {
        "runtime": {
        (....)
          "System.Net.Http.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "7.0.0.0",
            "fileVersion": "7.0.523.17405"
          },
(...)
      "NETStandard.Library/1.6.1": {
        "dependencies": {
        (...)
          "System.Net.Http": "4.3.0",
```

What am I missing? Why is it not `7.0.0` for **all** system dependencies?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `system dependencies like System.Net.Http still showing an earlier version ` they don't. They show that *the libraries you use* depend on those older versions. `Castle.Core/4.4.1` is a 3-year old version asks for `NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1` which depends on `System.Net.Http": "4.3.0` so the lowest applicable version is 4.3.0. That's not the version you actually get in .NET 7 project though because the runtime itself depends on Http 7.0.

Comment: So how do I get `dotnet` to create for me a "correct" dependency graph showing me what will actually be the packages being imported when building this solution? Do you know?

Comment: It's already correct. You already see that 7.0 is actually used, even though the old Castle.Rock library required 4.3. The `project.assets.json` shows what the libraries need, not the final versions used *after* it's flattened to individual packages

Comment: Why are you asking this? It sounds like there's another question behind the current one. Did you encounter some incompatibility or conflict perhaps, and think .NET is picking the wrong version? `project.assets.json` will help you by showing you the versions required by each library. It wouldn't do that if it only showed you the *final* versions used.

Comment: If you get a conflict error it's because one of the dependencies has version requirements that are incompatible with others. .NET Standard 1.6 is out of support for example. Something that has a 4.x upper version limit on .NET Standard or System.Net.Http won't work with System.Net.Http 7.

Comment: I am trying to make some code that can visualize dependencies for dotnet programs, but I cannot figure out how to make it realize that it's using the right system dependency. I apologize, but I still don't get what you mean by being already correct. I don't see 7.0 is actually used. Where do I see that?

Comment: Just to correct, I am trying to visualize the actual dependency tree. So I do not understand how to visualize Nuget packages that are all fine, but then I need to implement some special corner case for System packages? How do I know when to discriminate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254312/discussion-between-john-magistr-and-panagiotis-kanavos).